# clone the git repository non-interactively by passing token in the command

Tags: git, git-clone

I have a repository by name "**helloworld**" on the Github server - **github.infra.com**,
But the submodules for this repository are from different Github servers.

Now I want to clone my "**helloworld**" repository recursively by passing the personal access token in the git clone command.

Something like this: `git clone  --recursive "https://x-token-auth:<token>@<repo_url>"`. This works iff everything is in single Github server. 
But not in my case..! Could someone please help me here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't try to pass those credentials directly on the command line: you can set them on your global config, and the git will use them.

Use the [`url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) directive:

```
git config --global url."https://x-token-auth:<token>@<repo_url>".InsteadOf https://<repo_url>
git config --global url."https://x-token-auth:<token2>@<repo_url2>".InsteadOf https://<repo_url2>
```

Then do your `git clone --recursive`.

Comment: this solution works well on one of our github server (ex: github.infra.xxx.co.in) but the same is not working on different github server.

My doubt is is there any configuration on github server that blocks this kind of globally setting credentials or credentials helper...!?

Comment: @Rohith Yes, check if you have a credential helper which might cache the wrong credential. What does `git config credential.helper` return?